# Preencher o componente Select somente ao clicar

Tags: react

Estou com um projeto que ao entrar no componente ele carrega as informações do modal, pois o modal está com `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
    buscarPlantas();
}, []);
```

Mas quero que esta lista só carregue quando clique no componente.

Consegui colocando no `onFocus={buscarPlantas}` do componente. Só que ele não carrega a lista no componente.

```js
const [plantas, setPantas] = useState([]);

const buscarPlantas= () => {
    const plants = [];
    getBuscarPlantas().then((response) => {
        response.data.data.map(plant => (
            plants.push(plant.attributes)
        ))
    })
    setPlantas(plants);
}
```

```jsx
<Select
    value={age}
    onChange={handleChange}
    displayEmpty
    className={classes.selectEmpty}
    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
    onFocus={buscarPlantas}
>
    <MenuItem value="">
        <em className={classes.selectPlaceholder}>
            Selecionar plantas
        </em>
    </MenuItem>
    {
        plantas.map(planta => {
            return (
                <MenuItem key={planta} value={planta}>{planta}</MenuItem>
            )
        })
    }
</Select>
```

O que pode estar faltando ?

Comment: Qual biblioteca é essa? [`react-select`](https://react-select.com/)?

Comment: Não me parece uma boa ideia buscar ao clicar, porque o usuário irá precisar esperar carregar a lista depois de ter clicado e você precisará dar um indicador de carregamento para não parecer que a lista está vazia

Comment: Não tem nenhuma propriedade `onClick` no componente? Não retorna nenhum erro, warning, nada?

Comment: A biblioteca é import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

Comment: Bom, atpe concordo. Mas a idéia de carregar seria ao abrir o modal e não na página que tem o botão que faz abri o modal.      Exemplo.      Pesquisa de propriedades alem de trazer todas as propriedade ainda traz as plantas. Sendo que a planta só servirá se o usuário abrir o modal. Entendeu @RafaelTavares ?

Comment: @Shinforinpola No onclicck não funciona.   Como disse no 'onchange', vaino backend e retorna, mas não mostra na tela.

Comment: E por que você não popula esses itens no handler que usa para abrir a modal?